# Spring Session Redis web session expiration notifications not delayed until application is up again?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session

Currently using Spring Session Redis in a Spring Boot 2.5 web application.

The application correctly receives web session expiration notifications from Redis, but AFAIK **only if the application is up and running at that time**. It seems that if the backend is stopped at that time (crash, planned maintenance, ...), the notifications are not "kept" or "delayed" until the backend is up again, they are simply lost.

In https://redis.io/topics/notifications from *"if your Pub/Sub client disconnects, and reconnects later, all the events delivered during the time the client was disconnected are lost"* I understand that this is the standard Redis behavior.

Is this indeed the current Spring Session Redis behavior ?
Are there recommended solutions to "delay" the notifications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, this is the standard behavior of Redis Keyspace notifications.

If a key expires while the application is down, the expiry event cannot be processed, there is no way to delay the notification.

In the context of session expiration in Spring Session Data Redis, this means that the `SessionExpiredEvent`/`SessionDeletedEvent` will not fire if the application is down (crashed etc) when the Redis Keyspace notification is sent.
This will cause problems if you have a task dependent on these events.
It also means that resources may not get cleaned up properly.

However, from a security standpoint, the session will still expire correctly and the user will not be able to continue using the expired session.

If an application is performing a critical task on expiry, a different data store may be a better fit, given the "fire and forget" nature of Redis Pub/Sub.
Alternatively, having multiple nodes will make it unlikely that they will all be down at the time of receiving a notification.